# Save HTTP body with netcat

Tags: netcat

I can save the whole HTTP response from a server using netcat > output.txt, however this saves the HTTP response headers as well, if the body is text this isn't a problem as I can just ignore the headers when I read output.txt.

However if it's a binary file like an image, then I won't be able to view the image, how can I save just the body of a response using netcat or some other command with netcat's output piped to it?

Comment: Are you aware of `wget`?  Does that do what you want?

Comment: yes I am, however I'm currently limited to using netcat

Answer (score 1):

As hinted above wget (and lynx... and curl) can do a much better job than netcat but if you insist on it, you can filter out the header with your favourite scripting language. As the http header is terminated by \r\n\r\n which in unix-like systems (I guess that's where you are) actually means "all the header lines plus a line containing only \r", this is not as tough as it seems at first glance.

Using gawk (yes, GNU awk!, as RT is not known by other awk versions, AFAIK), this can be your command:

```
netcat ... | gawk 'NR==1,/^\r$/ {next} {printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' > something.out
```

If the question "why not just use print instead of this ugly method?" would pop up, the answer is: we don't know if the last record (what gawk thinks to be a record) is terminated with newline or not, and we also don't have clue if the existence of this last newline is significant or not. We can be sure if we write it there only if it was there in the input. RT will be empty if it was not so the output will be what was sent and not more.

Comment: For some reason this requires entering a newline on the terminal (hitting enter) to get the last line? Any idea why that is?